# c++ заполнение данными oracle

Tags: visual-studio, oracle

установлен oracle 11ee и visual studio 2017. Связь между бд и студией установил. Можно ли через консольный c++ проект работать с бд (нужно только 3 таблицы случайными данными заполнить) или только через c# wpf? Если можно то есть ли ссылка на гайд по заполнению таблиц? В гугле все запросы только по c# wpf.

Comment: Не совсем понятно, какова цель этой акции?

Comment: Нужно 3 таблицы записями в количестве 1000 штук заполнить. оракл к студии подключил, осталось цикл сделать. Нашел только гайды через c# windows form. Интересуюсь, есть ли способы через обычное c++ консольное приложение это сделать.

Comment: Можно конечно. Подключаетесь к БД, взываете sql выражение - insert into table select ..., затем commit. Всё вроде бы.